# Count seconds passed between pages in PHP

Tags: php, database, function

I'm trying to create a score result for a user that depends on how fast a user gets through pages. It's a little quiz game in html, and there are only 5 pages. What's the function required for setting the time on page 1, and then setting the end time on page 5 minus the time on page1. It should give the score to the user.

Also a sidequestion, I've created a user registration form in php that sends the user ID who plays the game to a database. When I know how to count the seconds between the two pages, I would like to know how to stamp that score onto each user and place them in an eventual highscore page. But that can come later.

If anyone can help me out with either or both, I would be very grateful. 
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use the `time()` function, save it in your session and build the difference when you want to have the time span passed.

Comment: I'm new to PHP, could you tell me how you'd go about writing the code for it? I imagine it's only two pieces of code on page 1 and highscore page (which is page 5 minus page 1) right?

Comment: Sorry, but you are expected to write your code yourself. The documentation provides all the information you need. _Read it._ It even brings examples: http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php

Comment: See this may be? [**Measuring PHP Page Load Time**](https://www.phpjabbers.com/measuring-php-page-load-time-php17.html)... This could be a **starting point**...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a session to keep track of the time passed between the start of page1 and the end of page5. Below is a partial example of page 1 start and after page 5.

For the query insert query, use prepared statements.

The php time() function gives you the number of seconds since 1 Jan 1970, so it should be sufficient to use the difference between end time - start time.

Page1.php

```
<?php

if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE){
    session_start();
}
$startTime = time();
$_SESSION['start_time'] = $startTime;
?>
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Page 1</h1>

        ...

    </body>
</html>
```

After page 5 (Result.php)

```
<?php
// get the current session if we have one, die with error if not (no start time present)
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE){
    session_start();

    if(!isset($_SESSION['start_time'])){
        die('no start time!');
    }
}

$_SESSION['end_time'] = time();
$timeDiff = $_SESSION['end_time'] - $_SESSION['start_time'];
?>

<html>
    <h1>Total time</h1>
    <?php echo $timeDiff; ?>
</html>

<?php
// Database connection and query
// set connection parameters
$host = "localhost";
$user = "root";
$password = ""; 
$database "your database name";

$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    die('Could not connect to database');
}

$query = "insert into QUIZ_LOG (col1, col2, ..... time_to_complete) values (?, ?, ... ?)";
$pst = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query);

if ($pst) {
    // set query parameters
    // ...
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($pst, "i", $timeDiff);

    mysqli_stmt_execute($pst);
} else {
    die('Could not insert data into db');
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and effort, but the second larger chunk of code supposed to be on result.php isn't working. An error message keeps saying "( ! ) Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.' in C:\wamp\www\game\highscore.php on line 23" ?

Comment: Because there is a ... in the middle of that file on line 23.  In place of the ... you need to specify your mysql connection parameters. Same to be said of the actual query a few lines below. See the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, William. I took a while for me to correctly implement the code into my quiz, and it works now. The time stamps you provided works perfectly. And I don't get the error I mentioned anymore but so far that particular code doesn't really seem to be doing anything. I get the "Could not insert data into db". I'll still look into but thanks!

Answer (score 0):

*"I would like to know how to stamp that score onto each user and place them in an eventual highscore page. But that can come later."*
- Actually, you could stop for a while before you start writing some codes, and think about what are the things that your website will need to do. Good start would be thinking of entities that your system will work with and their attributes (user, quiz, question, answer, etc.)

As of time, you can store the timestamp, when user started taking quiz in the database, could be an "quiz attempt" table/entity:

```
INSERT INTO quiz_attempt (..., time_started) VALUES (..., NOW() );
```